# Summation of two normal distribution in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, standard-deviation

I have a question about summing two normal distribution in Keras. So, I have 2 normal distributions called  **epsilon_1** ~ N(0,stdev1²) and **epsilon_2** ~ N(0,1 - stdev1²). If I want to sum those 2 normal distribution, is it correct if I only do this **epsilon_1** + **epsilon_2** in my code?

### My Code

```
stddev1 = 0.25
epsilon_mean = 0
epsilon_std_1 = stddev1
epsilon_std_2 = 1 - stddev1
epsilon1 = K.random_normal(shape=(1, 100),mean=epsilon_mean, stddev=epsilon_std_1)

epsilon2 = K.random_normal(shape=(1, 100),mean=epsilon_mean, stddev=epsilon_std_2)

epsilon = epsilon1 + epsilon2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is correct, and you can verify by checking the new mean and std of the new random variable, they should be equal to the sum of the originals respectively